# Need help with LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

All, I'm new to Linq to XML and have a question on how to generate XML, based on the following format prescribed by a vendor, from a `List<string>` containing the names of nested directories. - Please help.  Thanks

Vendor format:

```
<eccu>
  <match:recursive-dirs value="store" >  
    <match:recursive-dirs value="images" >  
       <revalidate>now</revalidate>  
    </match:recursive-dirs>  
  </match:recursive-dirs> 
</eccu>
```

Here's my code.  However as you can see it does not produce the correctly formatted results.:

```
// NOTE - textBox1.Text = 'http://www.someurl.com/dir1/di2/images'
    var dirs = (new Uri(textBox1.Text)).Segments.Select(dir => dir.Replace("/", String.Empty)).Where( dir => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dir)).ToList();
    var x = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null), new XElement("eccu", from s in dirs select new XElement("recursive-dirs", new XAttribute("value", s)), new XElement("revalidate", "now")));
```

This produces:

```
<eccu>
  <recursive-dirs value="dir1" />
  <recursive-dirs value="dir2" />
  <recursive-dirs value="images" />
  <revalidate>now</revalidate>
</eccu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is slightly incorrect as it needs to define the namespace "match".
The following code will produce XML with the namespace attribute correctly defined

```
XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
        XElement root = new XElement(aw + "Root",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "aw", "http://www.adventure-works.com"),
            new XElement(aw + "Child", "content")
        );
```

which produces

```
<aw:Root xmlns:aw="http://www.adventure-works.com"><aw:Child>content</aw:Child></aw:Root>
```

(taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.xmlns.aspx)
You'll need to adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: there we go...I'm not that knowledgable when it comes to xml.

Comment: Thanks very much for everyone's help. - Marc

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it in a hard coded fashion, assuming `match:recursive-dirs` is valid xml (I don't know).  Since you are talking about a list strings, I will need to see their format to work up a LINQ statement.

```
XElement xml = new XElement("eccu",
                   new XElement("match:recursive-dirs", 
                       new XAttribute("value", "store"),
                           new XElement("match:recursive-dirs", 
                                new XAttribute("value", "images"),
                                new XElement("revalidate", "now")
                          )
                       )
                   )
               );
```

based on [HookedOnLink.com](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)

**Edit based on comments**
It's not as pretty, but

```
string text = "http://www.someurl.com/dir1/di2/images";
var dirs = (new Uri( text )).Segments
                            .Select( dir => dir.Replace( "/", String.Empty ) )
                            .Where( dir => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( dir ) )
                            .ToList( );

var x = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration( "1.0", null, null ), 
                new XElement( "eccu" ) );

var eccu = x.Elements( ).First( );
XElement current = eccu;

foreach( var dir in dirs )
{
    XElement newXElement = new XElement( "recursive-dirs", 
                           new XAttribute( "value", dir ) );
    current.Add( newXElement );
    current = newXElement;
}

current.Add( new XElement( "revalidate", "now" ) );     
Console.Out.WriteLine( x.ToString());
```

produces

```
<eccu>
  <recursive-dirs value="dir1">
    <recursive-dirs value="di2">
      <recursive-dirs value="images">
        <revalidate>now</revalidate>
      </recursive-dirs>
    </recursive-dirs>
  </recursive-dirs>
</eccu>
```

Comment: Hard coding is not an option.  The list of directories could be 1 or it could be 10 layers deep.  The number depends on how many segments are parsed out of a particular URL.  Additionally, haveing the ':' is not valid.  I'm trying to figure that one out too.

Comment: @MarcS I didn't expect you would want a hard coded solution, but that shows you how to create an object graph that looks like you want.  Now that you have added some detail to your question I will readdress your specific request in an edit.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my question.  This stuff can be pretty complicated.

Comment: BTW - While my code snip attempts to do everything in a single line of code, there is no specific requirement to do so.

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  now I just need to get past the ":" issue.  The vendor requires a colon ':' as such <match:recursive-dirs value=>.  This one is stumping me too.

Comment: Question: When I inspect x.ToString() it has everything except for the declaration.  Is there another method I should call to get that as well?  The strange part is when I save the XML to a text file, it has it in there.  I'm going to be passing, via web service, the XML to a vendor.

Comment: @MarcS I don't know.  Sounds like an idea for a question on stackoverflow :)